# how to encrypt a data string with RSA private key in python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I'm new with encrypt and with python but I'm trying to encrypt a string data using RSA private key (SHA-1) with an existing pair keys in python.

For tests i wish to load my private key using it on source code (using a simple string or something) - if this is not possible i can load it from a file -

After the crypt is done i must encode it on base64 and for that i'm using `base64.b64decode(dataEnconde)`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's not much of an encryption as anyone with the public key could decrypt it. Normally, you'd encrypt with the public key (so that only the private key holder can decrypt it).

Comment: yes, i know. but is this case i must produce a hash code (encrypted) with my own private key to send it to a public department and them with the public key can decript. They made the rulles, i must obey.

Comment: What you are referring to is called a "signature".

Comment: Doing it this way ensures that only you could have possibly sent it.

Comment: exactly @Kendas, the idea of doing this is that - only me could be the sender -

Comment: @Thilo i saw that post before, i didnt get it- and i need to use PKCS1

Comment: That linked question has an example for making a PKCS1 signature.

Comment: @Thilo ok, i will study it. if that help me i will tell you. Thank you for explanation of what i am looking for :)